# Reading file in C# based on new line

Tags: c#, .net, csv, file-io, console-application

I have a file in C# which has keywords like this each present on new line

```
1234-hello I am here
121-Where are you
```

I want to read the file and write `1234-Hello` `121-Where` into another file, I have found lot of codes on internet that are based on comma seperated but couldn't find code to extract values on the basis of new line.

The `-` seperates the Number and the keyword I want to extract, like `1234-hello`

Comment: Can you please show us your efforts, thusfar?

Comment: `string.Split` and `File.ReadAllLines` should be enough here. Did you try anything and could you tell us why that did not work?

Comment: Are you saying your each column in CSV is separated by new line ? if that is the case how you determine difference between multiple records ?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel my efforts were I searched in on internet honestly

Comment: @user1765876 what should be the final output ? do you want to write `1234-Hello` and `121-Where`, or you want also split them by `'-'` and write seperately ?

Comment: Have a look at the StreamReader.ReadLine method at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string line = lines[i];
    string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[]{'-', ' '});
    int number = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
    string text = tokens[1];
    lines[i] = number + "-" + text;
}

File.WriteAllLines(path2, lines);
```

You probably want to add some error handling

- Check if any lines are returned
- Check if tokens.Length >= 2
- etc.

Comment: what if there is something like 123-asdasd )dfd

Comment: @user1765876 What's the problem? text will just be "asdasd )dfd" then.

Comment: this answer is not complete and wrong. OP wants to get the content before first white-space and you are not doing that.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot that part. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user1765876 Yeah, i guess I cheaped out where I had `//...` ;-) I updated my answer to momdify the current line.

Answer (score 2):

First read all lines, `Split` each line by *white-space*, get the first part and write the content to the new file:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path").Select(x => x.Split().First());

File.WriteAllLines("otherPath", lines);
```

This code should produce an output like this:

```
1234-Hello
121-Where
```